# How to go back to beginning of while True loop in async function?

Tags: python, telethon

I'm working on a hobby/study project where my Raspberry Pi controls a relay circuit in response to a Telegram message (with Telethon).

Everything works as it should, but only for one time. I can't get the script to return to the beginning of the `while True` loop after the relay has been activated. My guess is it's because of the ongoing async loop.

```
# Detect signal

while True:
    print("Begin loop")
    if detect.value == 1:
        print("Signaal detected")
    
        # Send message with buttons
        async def main():
            async with await TelegramClient("Test", api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token) as telegramclient:
                await telegramclient.send_message(notichannel, 'There is someone at the door', buttons=[[Button.inline('Open door', b'open'), Button.inline('Ignore', b'ignore')]])
        
        # Register callbackquery and open door    
                @telegramclient.on(events.CallbackQuery)
                async def callback(event):
                    if event.data == b'openen':
                        await event.answer("Door opened!", alert=True)
                        relay.on()
                        print("Door opened.")
                        time.sleep(5)
                        relay.off()
                        print("Door is open.")
                             
                    else:
                        print("Door not opened")
                        await event.answer("Door not opened.", alert=True)
     
                await telegramclient.run_until_disconnected()


        asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: You don't ever want to call `asyncio.run`  inside a loop. It should be run only once.

Comment: Is this actually how your code is indented?

Comment: If you directly `await` every async call's response, that's synchronous, not asynchronous. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

[`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) should only ever be called once. It is the starting point of a program.

Consider refactoring using this as an example.

```
async def run_telegram():
    # this function is what you call main in your program

async def main():
    # this is the actual main program
    while True:
        await run_telegram()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did refactor the file using your template, however the loop still runs only once. I can press the button in the Telegram message, the relay opens but then it just stays there, like the `run_telegram()` never ends. Maybe because of `telegramclient.run_until_disconnected`?